# Debug and solve app performance issue related to RAM and CPU usage

Tags: performance, garbage-collection, system, cpu-usage, ram

I was asked a question. Given a graph of CPU and RAM usage for a process. CPU was constant, but RAM was increasing linearly.

How would you debug to find out what the issue could be?
How are you going to solve it?

There is only one thing I could think of. That's a memory leak issue. The application code handles the resource improperly and hence  Garbage Collector can not clear the resource. We should capture the heap size increase and check the details.

Comment: Could be a memory leak. I would use a memory analyzer software at different points of time to see which specific part of the memory is growing and which part is constant.

Comment: RAM usage can not increasing linearly forever. Watch what happens when it hits the upper bound. Only then, you know. For example, if the RAM usage drops significantly at this point, you just have an ordinary non-concurrent garbage collector at work.

Comment: the first question is that whether the heap has reached xmx defined, if not, it could be just a normal behaviour how virtual memory works.